# Naming of a molecule

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

$\ce{H2C=C=O}$ what is the group of the  molecule? How to characterize it and how  is this dissimilar to ketone?

If we add $\ce{O2}$ with it then will we get $\ce{CO2}$?

Comment: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketene

Comment: Your question is unclear - the body does not seem to go with the title. Do you want to know the name of this molecule (ketene)?  or what the functional group is (ketene) and how it is different from the ketone group (complex)? or what happens when you burn it (the same thing that happens when you burn all organic compounds)? Could you focus your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As, your question isn't much clear and it needs to be focused little more.
From current state of this question, I can provide you the answers for specific questions that **I get to understand from its current state.**

> $\ce{H_2 \ \ C=C=O}$
>
> What is the group of the  molecule?

Well this is known as [ketene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketene).

> how to characterize it and how this is dissimilar to ketone?

[image: Structure of ketene]

> **Ketenes are generally very reactive, and participate in various cycloadditions. They will also undergo [2+2] cycloaddition reactions with electron-rich alkynes to form cyclobutenones, or carbonyl groups to form beta-lactones.**

[image: Structure of ketone]

> **Ketones engage in many organic reactions. The most important reactions follow from the susceptibility of the carbonyl carbon toward nucleophilic addition and the tendency for the enolates to add to electrophiles.**

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketene) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketone)

> If we add $\ce{O2}$ with it then will we get $\ce{CO2}$?

No! I hope structure of ketene and wikipedia articles make it clear to you why. :)

Also see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ketene_cycloaddition).